# array.reverse() in my *ngFor don't work in production

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, textarea

I don't know why, when I interact with my textarea, my _messagesList is reverse ASC and DESC everytime.

```
        <div class="chat__messages">
            <div *ngFor="let message of authService._messagesList.reverse()" [@fadeInOut] class="message" [ngClass]="session.User.id == message.Id_Sender ? 'myMsg' : 'otherMsg'">
                <p>{{message.Content}}</p>
                <span>{{message.createdAt | date: "HH:mm"}}</span>
            </div>
            <span class="loader" *ngIf="isLoading"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="chat__send">
            <textarea #textarea (input)="adjustTextareaHeight()" rows="1" [(ngModel)]="_content" (keydown.enter)="sendMessage();$event.preventDefault()" placeholder="Envoyer un message"></textarea>
            <button (click)="sendMessage()"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M498.1 5.6c10.1 7 15.4 19.1 13.5 31.2l-64 416c-1.5 9.7-7.4 18.2-16 23s-18.9 5.4-28 1.6L284 427.7l-68.5 74.1c-8.9 9.7-22.9 12.9-35.2 8.1S160 493.2 160 480V396.4c0-4 1.5-7.8 4.2-10.7L331.8 202.8c5.8-6.3 5.6-16-.4-22s-15.7-6.4-22-.7L106 360.8 17.7 316.6C7.1 311.3 .3 300.7 0 288.9s5.9-22.8 16.1-28.7l448-256c10.7-6.1 23.9-5.5 34 1.4z"/></svg></button>
        </div>
```

Edit : that work with "authService._messagesList.slice().reverse()" but I don't now why.
If someone can explain to me

Comment: with slice().reverse() you are reversing the slice, which is just a temporary array. Without slice, you are reversing the original array every time change detection runs. Adding answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling methods in your angular template which is very taxing on your change detection cycle so I would really recommend against that. Like, REALLY recommend against it.

Now, the reason it reverses is because of the above protest. Every time change detection runs, it executes the `reverse` method. Reverse isn't like slice or anything that returns a NEW array. Reverse flips the array IN PLACE and returns a reference to the original array, meaning the array in the service gets flipped. When change detection calls that method 5-10 times back to back to back, you will see it flip back and forth on you. That's one of the big reasons I recommended NEVER using methods in your template. Change detection will run them dozens of times over and it severely impacts the performance of your renderer. Try creating a getter for that array that console.logs the value every time it is retrieved and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

What Myles pointed out is true. Just sticking `array.reverse()` is going to cause the value to be continually updated as the reverse operation mutates itself. This can mean that the reverse happens twice and you don't realize, or users will see a constant flicker on the page.

I had to do something similar once, where I wanted a reverse chronological set of notifications to appear.

To handle this in my application, I created a second field called `invNotifications` to mirror my `notifications` field and then performed a cloned reversal of my original notifications. Here's a bit of the code for that. Note that I'm using Firebase to listen to notifications from the database, but you could do this any other way.

```js
  notifications: Notification[] = []
  invNotifications: Notification[] = []

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.firebase.subscribeUser(user => {
      if (!user) return
      if (!user.notifications) return
      this.notifications = user.notifications
      this.invNotifications = [...this.notifications].reverse()
    })
  }
```